# elif fRegistro: continue^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: python, if, else

```python
def processoF():
    sleep(30)
    finalizado = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('')  # processado e finalizado
    fRegistro = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('')  # processado e sem registro
    if finalizado:
        pyautogui.click(finalizado)
        pyautogui.click() #x e y do download
        sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click() #x e y do ok
        pyautogui.click() #x e y do confirmar
    elif fRegistro: continue
    else: processoF()
```

Nesse programa tento fazer com que o programa identifique duas imagens, se ele achar uma eu quero que ele clique nela, se ele achar a outra quero que ele não faça nada e se não for nenhuma das duas quero que verifique de novo, parece que a palavra "continue" não é adequada para a função, mas eu queria saber de um jeito que eu possa fazer o que eu to querendo fazer, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: `continue` só é usado dentro de um laço de repetição, `for`, `while`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Acho que encontrei a resposta, ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
L1 = False ou True
L2 = False ou True
def processo ():
    while L1 or L2 == False:
        if L1:
            print("L1 existe e fará o download")
            return True

        elif L2:
            print("isso n sera procesado")
            return True
processo()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).